# Concatenate rows and columns

Tags: r

I have a data set like this

```
       x    y   z
       a    5   4
       b    1   2
```

And i want concat columns and rows :

```
ay 5
az 4
by 1
bz 2
```

Thanks

Comment: @Sotos sorry i update my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `melt`, and `paste` but you will need to make your rownames a variable, i..e

```
df$new <- rownames(df)
m_df <- reshape2::melt(df)
rownames(m_df) <- paste0(m_df$new, m_df$variable)
m_df <- m_df[-c(1:2)]

m_df
#   value
#ax     5
#bx     1
#ay     4
#by     2
#az     3
#bz     1
```

After your edit, you don't need to convert rownames to a variable so just,

```
m1_df <- reshape2::melt(df)
m1_df$new <- paste0(m1_df$x, m1_df$variable)

m1_df
#  x variable value new
#1 a        y     5  ay
#2 b        y     1  by
#3 a        z     4  az
#4 b        z     2  bz
```

You can then tidy your data frame to required output

Answer (score 1):

with `dplyr-tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  gather(var, val, -x) %>% 
  mutate(var=paste0(x, var)) %>% 
  select(var, val)%>%
  arrange(var)

#  var val
#1  ay   5
#2  az   4
#3  by   1
#4  bz   2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)

# Create dataframe
x <- data.frame(x = c(5, 1),
                y = c(4, 2),
                z = c(3, 1),
                row.names = c('a', 'b'))

# Convert rowname to column and melt
x <- tibble::rownames_to_column(x, "rownames") %>%
  melt('rownames') 

# assign concat columns as rownames
row.names(x) <- str_c(x$rownames, x$variable)

# Select relevant columns only
x <- select(x, value)

# Remove names from dataframe
names(x) <- NULL

> x

ax 5
bx 1
ay 4
by 2
az 3
bz 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option in `base R`

```
stack(setNames(as.list(unlist(df1[-1])), outer(df1$x, names(df1)[-1], paste0)))[2:1]
```